# Better way to draw lines?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for an easier, more efficient way to draw lines from one point to another. Right now, I'm doing a manual div - CSS kind of combination. I'm using the CSS to force the lines into a favorable position like in the image below, but as you can see, it's very hard to code the lines one by one to force them into that kind of position.

[image: Picture]

This is the HTML:

```
                <div id="line1A"></div>
                <div id="line1B"></div>
                <div id="line1C"></div>
                <div id="line1D"></div>
                <div id="line1E"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#line1A{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px #000 dotted;
    width:240px;
}

#line1B{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px #000 dotted;
    width:270px;

    left:230px;
    top:113px;

    transform:rotate(24deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(24deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(24deg);
}

#line1C{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px #000 dotted;
    width:340px;

    left:187px;
    top:163px;

    transform:rotate(42deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(42deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(42deg);
}

#line1D{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px #000 dotted;
    width:400px;

    left:160px;
    top:223px;

    transform:rotate(54deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(54deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(54deg);
}

#line1E{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px #000 dotted;
    width:500px;

    left:107px;
    top:273px;

    transform:rotate(61deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(61deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(61deg);
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make this an easier endeavor?

Comment: Are you looking for a canvas?

Comment: Why don't you give a try to HTML5 canvas as pointed by @vp_arth

Comment: You can see my **Update** for a scripting solution using *jQuery*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your requirement need us to deal with simple Maths a little. The idea is you have the line element (which can be a div or a `li` as in my demo) normally appear horizontally. You just need to specify the `left` fixed, the `top` is changed depending on the point from which the line starts. Then you need to calculate the `width` for it correctly (with simple pitago formula applied in a perpendicular triangle), you also need to calculate the rotating angle to use for the `rotate` (use `rotate3d` for smooth rendering) function which can be used in a `transform` property. When all the values are calculated, you just need to write the CSS **carefully**.

**Simple math**:

[image]

We have:

- c<sup>2</sup> = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>   from this you can calculate the width (c) of the line, in my demo the `a` is fixed at `250px`.
- cos(alpha) = a / c   from this you can calculate the rotating angle alpha.
- The offset top is always 100px (in my demo) , so you can calculate it easily for a point.
- The offset left is always 10px (in my demo).

Here are the code details which I write for only 2 points (which have all the lines connected to other points):

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
  <!-- 11 to all -->
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <!-- 12 to all --> 
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul {
  width:500px;
  height:520px;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at 10px 10px, black, black 10px, transparent 10px);
  background-size:50% 100px;
  position:relative;    
  padding:0;
}
ul > li {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  height:0;
  border-top:2px dotted black;
  left:10px;
  -webkit-transform-origin:left 50%;
}

/* point 11 */
ul > li:nth-child(1) {
  width:50%;    
  top:10px;     
}
ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 269px;
  top:10px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate3d(0,0,1, 21deg); 
}

ul > li:nth-child(3) {
  width:320px;
  top:10px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate3d(0,0,1, 38.62deg);
}
ul > li:nth-child(4) {
  width: 390px;
  top:10px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate3d(0,0,1, 50.13deg);
}
ul > li:nth-child(5) {
  width: 472px;
  top:10px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate3d(0,0,1, 58deg);
}
ul > li:nth-child(6) {
  width: 559px;
  top:10px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate3d(0,0,1, 63.43deg);
}

/* point 12 */
ul > li:nth-child(7) {
  width: 269px;
  top:110px;    
 -webkit-transform:rotate3d(0,0,1, -22deg);
}
ul > li:nth-child(8) {
  width: 320px;
  top:210px;    
  -webkit-transform:rotate3d(0,0,1, -38.62deg);
}
ul > li:nth-child(9) {
  width: 390px;
  top:310px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate3d(0,0,1, -50.13deg);
}
ul > li:nth-child(10) {
  width: 472px;
  top:410px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate3d(0,0,1, -58deg);
}
ul > li:nth-child(11) {
  width: 559px;
  top:510px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate3d(0,0,1, -63.43deg);
}
```

**NOTE**: I **can't** write all the points for you because it requires too much work. This demo also is not what you can copy and paste to use right. It's just an example demonstrating how you can achieve what you want. Note that I choose the distance between 2 lines as `100px`, the horizontal distance between 2 points as `250px` (you can see it clearly in the code).

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/frWnj/4/)

**UPDATE**:
- I think it's better to use script for this kind of render, here is the [Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/frWnj/5/) using script.

Comment: Isn't `rotate3D` more heavy than `rotate`?

Comment: @vp_arth it depends on the things to render. In this case (which rotate just on the Z plat, similarly to `rotateZ`), I think there is **just a little** difference in how much work they do, while the main purpose to use `rotate3d` is to enable the graphics acceleration engine. As tested myself, you can use `rotate` in IE 11 or FF 28 but other browsers including Chrome, Opera do not render it smoothly. Hence using `rotate3d` is the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript and HTML5 canvas to create lines based on XY coordinate pair. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Answer (score 0):

I write simple js function for you:

```
function drawLine(el, x, y, x1, y1) {
  var line = document.createElement('div');
  line.className = 'line';
  var dX = x1 - x;
  var dY = y1 - y;
  var l  = Math.sqrt(dX*dX+dY*dY)
  line.style.width = l.toFixed(2)+'px';
    var rad = dX ? Math.atan(dY/dX): Math.PI/2;
    var deg = 2*rad*90/Math.PI;
  line.style.left = (Math.abs(dX)/2-l/2+Math.min(x, x1))+'px';
  line.style.top  = (dY/2+Math.min(y, y1))+'px';

  cssExpand(line, 'transform', 'rotate('+deg.toFixed(4)+'deg)');

  el.appendChild(line);
}
```

Usage: `drawLine(container, 0, 0, 400, 100);`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/3qhv4/)

You can also wrap it to get what you want.
Something like:

```
function connect(right, left) {
  var y1 = getY(right);
  var y2 = getY(left);
  drawLine(document.body, firstColX, y1, secondColX, y2);
}
```